# Could I learn more about the flying Shiva with wings?

Tags: shiva, shaivism

I had a vision of such a Shiva. I've read about Sharabha. How do Hindus respect Sharabha?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you mean "Where could I learn ..?" or "How could I learn?"

Answer (score 3):

Sharbha is mentioned in many of the scriptures such as Ling Puran, Shiv puran, Sharbha Upanishad, Kalika Puran, Skandha Puran, even in Shilpashastra of Kaliagama.

Here are some references,

Sharabha Upanishad~
10th Upanishad from Atharvaved,

> 7. He, the Supreme Lord, assuming the terrible form called ‘Sarabha’ (divine bird), the mighty one killed (was about to kill) Nrisimha, the world destroyer (after drinking the blood of Hiranyaksha, Nrisimha became very troublesome as he could not digest it). The lords of Devas requested him who was taking the life of him (Nrisimha) by his feet, ‘Do not, O, mighty one, do not take away the life of Vishnu, the person, in this dead night.’
> 8. The Lord by His sharp nails opened (his body and drank the venomed blood) out of compassion, and the mighty one, clad by his skin, is called ‘Virabadra’ (the pacifier of heated ones).
> 9. (The definition of Sarabha). The Saras are the jivas. They are always shining (Bha) in His body. Hence the (all) consumer Brahman is called Sarabha. O the great sage, the direct giver of Salvation.

Thus this is what the meaning of Sharabha is given in Sharabha Upanishad.

Kalika Purana-
Chapter Sarasar Nirupan,

> He became Bhairav (terrific) with 8 legs upwards and downwards.
> His form had a long nose, had huge nails in claws, and had complexion that of black coal. He had huge body with a huge mouth with 8 molar tooths, a tail carrying jathas, and had a terrific form with huge ears. He had four legs in front and four on backside. He made great terrific noise and was jumping again and again.

When Sharbha appeared to Kill Varaha in Kalika Puran. Varaha called Narsimha to his aid. Thus Sharbha killed Narsimha first and then Varaha finally.

Ling Mahapurana,
Chapter 95, the chaos of Narsimha,

> Soon after Mahadeva assume the form of Shrabha and approach the haughty man lion. The lord in the form of sharabha took away his life and was worship by Devas. 60-61

Shiva Mahapuran,
Shatarudra Samhita, Chapter 12, Shlok 8-16

> 8. He had a thousand hands and wore matted hair. His head was adorned by the crescent moon. He appeared like a bird with wings and beak. His body was fierce and fully developed.
> 9. His fangs were very sharp. Adamantine daws were his weapons. His neck was black in colour. He had huge arms and four legs. He was blazing like fire
> 10. His voice was resonant and terrible like the rumbling sound of the clouds that gather at the end of a Yuga. His three eyes were as wide and blazing as the fire of the evil spirit of great fury.
> 11. His fangs and lips were clearly visible. He was producing a hissing sound of Huṃkāra. Śiva of such a form appeared in sight
> 12. At his very vision Viṣṇu lost his strength and exploit. He assumed a lustre of the flickering glow-worm beneath the sun.
>     13-14. Fluttering with his wings, and tearing the navel and legs he bound the legs of the Man-lion with his tail and his hands with his own hands. He struck his chest, caught hold of Viṣṇu. It expanded in the sky along with the gods and the sages.
>     15-16. Like a vulture seizing a serpent he fearlessly caught hold of Viṣṇu, lifted him up and fell him to the ground. At the time of flight he was excessively oppressed, being hit with the wings. Then Lord Śiva took Viṣṇu and flew upwards.

Sharabha according to Kalikagama.—

> The body of Sharabha should be that of a bird of golden hue, having two red eyes; and it should have two up-lifted wings and eight limbs. Sharabha, which is said to be mightier than an elephant, should have the fierce face of a lion grinning widely, having tusks and   wearing kirita makuta. The torso of Sharabha resembles that of human male having four hands .The lower part of its body should resemble that of a lion having four legs, sharp claws and a tail. Sharabha should be shown carrying the figure of Narasimha in his human form with upraised folded hands, anjali-mudra.

Now, as to the question you asked to how does one pays respect to Sharbha?

Thus in temples dedicated to Sharbha, various vidhanas are followed as per Shaiv agams including Rudrabhishekam, chantings of Shivsahasranaam stotram,  Sharbhastakam, Sharbha Sahasranaam stotram, Nigrahadaruna Saptakam,  Malamantram (PS- These are purely tantric stotra from Akash Bhairav Kalpa so it's better to not chant those, if uninitiated as Sharbha in itself is Ugramurti).
Instead if personally you want to do Sharabha puja, you can chant Puranokt Rudram which was given by Shree Krushn and do Abhishekam of parthiv ling or in Shivalaya by invoking Sharbha in those.

कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।